# javascript slider picture not centered

Tags: javascript, slider

I am doing a javascript slider for practice.

However, the picture in the slider is not centered.

Here's the link: http://eddieli.org/flee/

Which part of the coding have I done wrong?

The pictures are not aligned with the slider...

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i added `position: relative; left: -40px;` to the li of the sliders `#container #left_col #slider li`, and they get aligned, i don`t know which size images are, but you must always check the starting position before doing the slider itself, you must check all styles fit right.